# iOS-ntp framework not compiling xcode 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ntp

I installed the ios-ntp framework from https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp as written on the page, however the framework seems to be a bit updated and not configured for xcode 6. After adding the framework and attempting to use it as so:

In my `AppDelegate.h`

Imported the framework in my:

```
#import <ios-ntp/ios-ntp.h>
```

Fired framework methods:

```
//try out ntp timer
[NetworkClock sharedNetworkClock];

NSDate* systemTime = [NSDate date];
NSDate* networkTime = [NSDate networkDate];

NSLog(@"system time = %@",systemTime);
NSLog(@"network time = %@",networkTime);
```

I am not able to compile and get the following error:

```
ld: warning: ignoring file /Users/royhermann/Desktop/Dev/Blackout/ios-ntp.framework/ios-ntp, missing required architecture x86_64 in file /Users/royhermann/Desktop/Dev/Blackout/ios-ntp.framework/ios-ntp (2 slices)
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_NetworkClock", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in BOAppDelegate.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

I did read about possible solutions to similar warning, but was unable to find a solution to solve the problem. I have currently reverted to original project/target settings and am using "standard architectures" in my build settings.

How can I solve the problem and compile/utilize ios-ntp? Thanks!

Comment: you're using cocoapods?

Comment: Yes for other frameworks, but I imported ios-ntp manually (just added the files to my project)

Comment: ah, I got the question

Comment: Yes, i guess so - it says on the git page that its a static framework

Comment: you can't do anything, static library is not compiled for x86_64 architecture, seems they dropped simulator support. so another way is to download and compile for x86_64 architecture too.

Comment: i was getting the same error but for arm64 when trying to compile for my device. What do you mean by "download and compile for ..." - there is only one source to download from, so I don't really have the choice

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64722/discussion-between-l0gg3r-and-roy-h).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, some nice person uploaded a xcode 6 compliant version. https://github.com/jbenet/ios-ntp